# How to put the string entered into a character array in C++?

Tags: c++, string, getchar

Now, I am facing with such a problem: Compare two strings without using "strcmp" in library function.

I have defined the function "mystrcmp" correctly, but I also have to put the string entered into a character array. How can I realize it?

Here is my wrong codes:

```
char a1[100],a2[100];
int j=0;
do
{
    cin>>a1[j];
    j=j+1;
}while(getchar()!=10);
int k=0;
do
{
    cin>>a2[k];
    k=k+1;
}while(getchar()!=10);

cout<<j<<"  "<<k<<"\n";
```

I want to see if the loops are correct through j and k. Unfortunately, the results are wrong.
For example, when I enter "abcdefg" and "gfedcba", I get the result "j=4, k=4".

What's wrong with my codes? How can I correct it?

I'm looking forward to your answers. Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for C++ solutions? - all your code and the mention of strcmp is C - ad would fail any code review for C++

Comment: Please post the entire function, not just the body.

Comment: do you want 10 char long string

Comment: Why are you not using `std::string`?

Comment: @Mark: If it were possible to left shift by a string literal (as in `cout<<j<<"  "<<k<<"\n";`), then this code could be C... but no.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue - but the rest is plain C if C++ should be strings

Comment: @Mark It's C++ if it's compiled with a C++ compiler.

Comment: Can you describe ***in words*** how you would compare two strings? If you can do that, it's a lot easier to implement in C++ (or any other language).

Comment: I don't even understand what you're program is supposed to be accomplishing.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Thanks for your advice. I will follow it next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using the value 10 in your code? Don't use integer literals in place of character constants, because when you attempt to run this code on a computer that uses the EBCDIC character set you'll notice that '\n' has the value 37, not 10. Use '\n' instead of 10.

Don't mix getchar and cin code. That's a pretty bad idea, because they both consume one character each. In other words, getchar() is consuming one byte, and cin is consuming one byte, so you're consuming two bytes per loop and only storing one of those bytes. If you're going to use getchar, I think you mean something like this:

```
for (int c = getchar(); c >= 0 && c != '\n'; c = getchar()) {
    a1[j++] = c;
}
a1[j] = '\0';
```

The same sort of thing using C++'s cin:

```
for (int c = cin.get(); cin.good() && c != '\n'; c = cin.get()) {
    a1[j++] = c;
}
a1[j] = '\0';
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You gave me a new idea —— using int to deal with characters.

Answer (score 0):

This is dangerous code. You can write out of a1 & a2 bounds. Use functions made for this, for example `cin.getline`

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/